# Remove minimize (?) button in Xfce

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

Is it possible to remove this little button from this window?

[image]

I'm using Linux Mint with Xfce GUI and MindnigtWhite theme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the "shade" button; you can remove it in `xfwm4-settings` (or the "Settings" → "Window Manager" control panel):

[image]